# selecting for an id with a variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically display some data in an array that is returned from an ajax request. I know i have successfully retrieved the array from the server. My problem appears to be displaying the array on screen.  I think I am making a mistake with designating the id of an element using a variable, and then trying to select for that ID with jquery.  I have tried all sorts of combinations (playing with the single and double quotations ) as suggested by similar posts but none of them seem to work. Please can someone advise?

my code:

```
   success: function(data){
      $.each(data, function(i, element){
          // display 'filename' and corresponding 'title'.
          var id_name = element['filename'];
          mainDiv.append('<div class="wrapper_div" id='+id_name+'></div>');

          $('#' + id_name).append('<input type="checkbox" name="checkvalue[]" class="check_box" disabled="disabled" value='+element['filename']+'>');
          $('#' + id_name).append('<div>' + element['filename'] + '</div>');
          $('#' + id_name).append('<div>' + element['title'] +  '</div>');

         });
        }
```

I know my data is there as the following code works. The items are displayed. But i really need the above code:

```
   mainDiv.append('<input type="checkbox" name="checkvalue[]" class="check_box" disabled="disabled" value='+element['filename']+' >');
          mainDiv.append('<div>' + element['filename'] + '</div>');
          mainDiv.append('<div>' + element['title'] +  '</div>');
```

Comment: look at your brackets carefully, try "<div>" + element['filename'] + "</div>", "<div>" + element['title'] +  "</div>", '<input type="checkbox" name="checkvalue[]" class="check_box" disabled="disabled" value='+element["filename"]+' >'

Comment: ```id='+id_name+'``` should be ```id="'+id_name+'"```, Your ID isn't being created as you expect it to be

Answer (score 2):

Update your mainDiv.append to this

```
mainDiv.append('<div class="wrapper_div" id="' + id_name + '"></div>');
```

Also this line

```
$('#' + id_name).append('<input type="checkbox" name="checkvalue[]" class="check_box" disabled="disabled" value= "' + element['filename'] +'">');
```

Comment: i've modified my code to yours but it is still not working.  I have also updated my post.

Comment: Could you take the time to explain why? That way people can learn something useful from the answer that they might apply to other, similar, situations.

Answer (score 2):

Are you closing out the `$.each()` correctly? I don't see the closing bracket and parenthesis in your code sample. It runs as expected when I add the closing bracket and parenthesis.

[this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJwvva?editors=001) shows the function executing correctly, so your issue may be with something else in your code.

```
 success: function(data){
      $.each(data, function(i, element){
          // display 'filename' and corresponding 'title'.
          var id_name = element['filename'];
          mainDiv.append('<div class="wrapper_div" id='+id_name+'></div>');

          $('#' + id_name).append('<input type="checkbox" name="checkvalue[]" class="check_box" disabled="disabled" value='+element['filename']+'>');
          $('#' + id_name).append('<div>' + element['filename'] + '</div>');
          $('#' + id_name).append('<div>' + element['title'] +  '</div>');
      });
 }
```